# How to get nearby value from Database in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table in my database which is related to another table, there are 2 fields in database one is `minprice` and another is `maxprice`, these fields have floating value stored in database (eg. 23.47 Lac). Now i want nearby value from database on 1 field, I am using `round($r->minprice);` for this, but it's giving me the value between (1-100), But i want like this (Suppose a property have price 13.45 lac, then it could be show min 10 lac on display), What will be the condition for this.

Here are my code....

```
$praa = round($r->minprice);
$prop->meta_desc = $best." ".$subCat[0]->cat_name." ".$in." ".$cities->name
                    ." ".$Location->locations.","." ".$r->title." ".$subCat[0]->cat_name
                    ." ".$under." ".$praa." " ."Lac";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```php
$praa = (int) round($r->minprice, -1);
```

It'll round to the nearest 10th.

[Live demo here](https://implode.io/vPe1aP)